# How to comment previous answers in SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, comments

I have comments on answers to some questions but I see no GUI affordance to make my own comments. However, I can reply to comments in my own answers. Any level required to comment?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work?noredirect=1&lq=1 > "All users may comment on their own posts and any answers to their own questions.".

Answer (score 4):

50 reputation is required for adding comments (apart from comments to your own answers), see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

PS: Such questions should be on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).